# What LLVM-types besides void arent allowed for alloca instructions

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing an LLVM pass that adds an alloca instruction for an arbitrary type into a basic block using IRBuilder.CreateAlloca(type). The type is taken from another existing instruction that was added by the compiler. However, in some rare edge case, this leads to an error during further compilation, meaning that this alloca instruction doesnt work. The only thing varying is the type. The type is guranteed to be a valid LLVM type object.

Is there any type in LLVM, that isnt allowed to be allocated on the stack? I'm already excluding void type from this operation, so thats not it. Its also not a vector, struct or aggregate type, as I tried to exclude those before.

As I'm using a build system that I cant easily debug, I can't really figure it out by myself unfortunately. I was only able to pinpoint the source of the error to this exact line of code.